# Send slider value from python to Ableton Live

Tags: midi, ableton

I want to send to Ableton Live float number that will set the instrument parameter from code (python). I try to edit midi remove script (no documentation and not worked). I can send note tone and velocity through MIDI and it works, but i can't send slider or knob value

Comment: Interesting question. I don't think you'll get a good answer here, though. You'll have a better chance finding a decent solution @ Stack Overflow. Try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python

Comment: Ah. I see you've already asked there, as well. What exactly are you trying to do? Are you developing software or are you troubleshooting an issue with your hardware?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean to say:
*"MIDI <strike>remove</strike> **remote** script"?*

I haven't seen the code. And I'm not sure I fully understand your question,  but apparently; the value of the sliders 7th parameter should to be set to: `"not"`.

Otherwise it will drop any changes initiated by Live.

Does that help? Or is it a different problem?

---

<sub>*https://www.ableton.com/answers/midi-remote-script-bcf-slider-feedback*</sub>